# How can I have multiple route files in server file using express (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to put my routes into multiple files. if I only use one route file in server.ts like this, all works fine

server.ts:

```
require('./articles/routes/blog-article.routes')(app);
```

article.route.ts

```
module.exports = app => {

    const article = require('../controllers/artilce.controller');

    app.post('/api/blog/addArticle', article.addArticle);

    app.get('/api/blog', article.getAllArticles);

    app.get('/api/blog/:articleId', article.getArticleById);

    app.delete('/api/blog/deleteArticle/:articleId', article.deleteArticle);

    app.put('/api/blog/editArticle/:articleId', article.editArticle);
};
```

But if I add in server.ts `require('./tags/routes/article-tags.routes')(app);` it doesn't work.

article-tags.routes.ts:

```
module.exports = app => 

    const articleTags = require('../controllers/article-tags.controller');
    app.get('/api/blog/articleTags', articleTags.getAllArticleTags);

};
```

Comment: What not works? Do you have an error in your log?

Comment: Are you missing `{` after `app =>` ?

Comment: If the order in server.ts is 
``require('./articles/routes/blog-article.routes')(app);
require('./tags/routes/article-tags.routes')(app);``
I have a 500 error "msg":"Error retrieving article with id articleTags"} and this error message I show when can not get article with specific id, but in this case I want to get article tags.
If the order is 
`require('./tags/routes/article-tags.routes')(app)
require('./articles/routes/blog-article.routes')(app);` 
it works correct, but in network I see multiple /blog/articleTags get requests